# Ranges and "for loops" within python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

I have used a for loop.

```
for i in range (100, 40, -2):
    print ("T-minus:")
    print (i)
```

The code is executed with the final output being T-minus: 42

I understand that the loop has been executed up to, but not including, the value 
 40. I was curious as to how I would go about ensuring that both both "poles" of a range are specified/included? Would I need to artifically "low-ball" my range? So for example, if I decremental factor is -2, and I want the range to stop at 40, would I then have to state 38, making my code the following:

```
for i in range (100, 38, -2):
    print ("T-minus:")
        print (i)
```

?

My question specifically pertains to loops.

Comment: No, my question pertains to loops specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [`range(start, stop, step)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) document:

> if `step` is negative, the last element is the smallest `start + i * step` greater than `stop`.

Since you have `step` of -2, you may use any value among 38 or 39 as `stop`.